# Solr error - Stream Body is disabled

Tags: solr, document

I'm deleting documents from browser URL.

I'm using Solr-7.4.0

I'm using this query for delete document

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```

This is return below error message.

```
{
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Stream Body is disabled. See http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/requestdispatcher-in-solrconfig.html for help",
    "code":400}}
```

I also tried with

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
```

but not get any luck.
This return below message:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1}}
```

but documents not deleting.

I'm using DIH for import data.

**my data-config.xml file is**

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\SQL2017;databaseName=mydatabase"   user="sa" password="mypassword"/>

    <document>
      <entity name="Product"  
        pk="Id"
        query="select Id, [Name] from Product"
        deltaImportQuery="SELECT Id, [Name] from Product WHERE Id='${dih.delta.id}'"
        deltaQuery="SELECT Id FROM Product  WHERE updated_at > '${dih.last_index_time}'"
        >
         <field column="Id" name="Id"/>
         <field column="Name" name="Name"/>       
      </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it by postman

**Method:** POST
**Content-Type:** application/json
**Body:**

```
{
    "set-property": [{
            "requestDispatcher.requestParsers.enableRemoteStreaming": true
        },
        {
            "requestDispatcher.requestParsers.enableStreamBody": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**URL:** http://localhost:8983/api/cores/test5/config

after that run below URL:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test5/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3E*:*%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true
```

and it's working fine.

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to open the **solrconfig.xml** file and edit it directly.

The default value should look like this:

```
<requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true"
                multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
                formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"
                addHttpRequestToContext="false"/>
```

We need to add the **enableStreamBody** attribute:

```
<requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true"
                enableStreamBody="true"
                multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
                formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"
                addHttpRequestToContext="false"/>
```

Just remember to reload the collection in Solr so the changes will be applied.

Comment: Hello, 
what do you mean by reloading the collection ? how is that done in solr ? 
thanks a lot