# Solr 8 upgrade and stream.body

Tags: solr

I'm upgrading Solr from 6.x to 8.x.  In the past, we used to build our request thusly in our PHP script:

```
$aPostData = array( 
  'stream.body' => '{"add": {"doc":{...stuff here...}}',
  'commit' => 'true',
  'collection' => 'mycollection',
  'expandMacros' => 'false'
);

$oBody = new \http\Message\Body();
$oBody->addForm($aPostData);
```

sending it to our Solr server at /solr/mycollection/update/json.  That worked just fine in 6.x but now that I've upgraded to 8.x, I'm receiving the following response from Solr

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1
  },
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"missing content stream",
    "code":400
  }
}
```

Digging around I ran across the following

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10748

and

[Solr error - Stream Body is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416042/solr-error-stream-body-is-disabled/51420987)

I tried following the suggestions of both answers.  For the first one, I now see a file called "configoverlay.json" in my ./conf directory and it has those settings.  For the second answer, I set it up so my requestParsers node had those attributes.  However, neither worked.  I've searched around but at this point I'm at my wits end.  How can I make it so that I can continue using "stream.body"?  If I shouldn't be using "stream.body" is there some other request var that I can/should use when sending my data?  I couldn't find anything in the documentation.  Perhaps I was looking in the wrong place?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thnx,
Christoph

Comment: Any reason why you can't submit data as the POST request body instead? `ext-http` seems to support that with the body by using `append` directly, and then giving the request params as regular url arguments? The `/update/json` endpoint should probably also be just `/update` now, with the content-type properly set to `application/json` for the request instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh, what do you mean by "as the POST request body instead"?  Is that not what I'm doing in the first snippet above?

Comment: You're sending it as POST variables - that's not the same as sending as the main POST body. In that case the only thing present in the POST body would be the XML, and there would be no need to attach it to a variable. That's where the problem arises - I'm not familiar enough with `ext-http` to say how you'd do that, but seeing as there is no particular reason why you're doing it this way, I'll see if I can take a look later today.

Comment: So I tried adding it to the body. Here is the revised code

```$aPostData = array( 'commit' => 'true', 'collection'  => 'mycollection', 'expandMacros' => 'false');

$oBody = new \http\Message\Body();
$oBody->addForm($aPostData);
$oBody->append(''{"add": {"doc":{...stuff here...}}'');```

When I serialize the object to see what it's sending, I see that it does seem to have been added to the body of the request (as opposed to request params). I'm still seeing the same error. I didn't change the content type because when I did that I got a different error -- it could not parse the json